# find all data using same field and different values in mysql sequelize

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sequelize.js

I need to find the data using same field on mysql,
but different values.
but i geetting empty values in response.

I tried the $and condition to find the data on sequelize.
but it getting not data in response.

```
 exports.multibranchdata = (req, res) => {

 const wherequery = { 
             $and: [{ id: { eq: 1 } },
                    { id: { eq: 2 } }
                   ] };
 branch.findAll(wherequery)

.then(data => res.status(200).send(data))

.catch(Sequelize.ValidationError, err => 
 res.status(422).send(err.errors[0].message))

.catch(err => res.status(400).send(err.message));
 };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try OR query :-

```
 const wherequery = { 
             $or: [{ id: { eq: 1 } },
                    { id: { eq: 2 } }
                   ] };
```